# PHP not saving data to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost

I feel like I'm getting closer to figuring out why PHP **is not saving data to my database**.
I've tried learning PHP and MySQL from numerous tutorials and all have failed me.

So... I feel like there may be something that I haven't been specifying when trying to connect to a MySQL database.

In a recent tutorial that simply outputs text from an input to a table in MySQL, I got an Error stating that the server "localhost" was not found. 
My Apache has been installed on port 60 (not the default port 80). So I figured that that might be the problem. I tried adding `localhost:60` to the `mysqli_connect` rather than `localhost` itself and the error disappeared!

**There is still a problem though:** 1. It takes forever to load the demo.php page (see code below). 2. The data **still** isn't being added....

Here is the code (I converted it from the original MySQL on the video, to MySQLi and added comments):

**demo.php:**

```
   <?php

    define('DB_NAME', 'forms1');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:60');

    // stored in a variable to TEST if it's working
    $link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST);

    // TEST if a link has been established (connection)
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect:' . mysqli_error($link));
    }
    // same as above
    $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link,DB_NAME);

    if(!$db_selected) {
        die('Can\t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error($link));
    }
    // Check SUCCESS with commented command below
    // echo 'Connected successfully.';

    // stored in a variable to shorten
    $value = $_POST['input1'];

    // stored in a variable to TEST
    $sql = "INSERT INTO demo (input1) VALUES ('$value')"; 

    if(!mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    }

    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

**demo-form.php:**

```
<form action="demo.php" method="post" />
<p>Input 1: <input type="text" name="input1" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I've also had **the same problem** with another code, see the thread here: 
[PHP database won't save data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438062/php-database-wont-save-data)

I **really hope** that someone can help me here. 
It's a shame that I haven't even gotten the basis to work yet...

Thanks!

Comment: wide open to SQL injection attack

Comment: Change all `mysql_error` to `mysqli_error` you're mixing SQL functions which, well... don't "mix". ;-)

Comment: The apache port and mysql port are two different things.  You want your mysql port when configuring your connection.  Additionally, by default `localhost` attempts to connect with a socket by default on a unix machine whereas `127.0.0.1` will utilize tcp/ip... the latter is where you need to concern yourself with a port.

Comment: @Dagon This is for learning purposes, I realize it is vulnerable, Fred-ii- I'll edit the code, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Fixing those may very well fix your code. I've seen that happen before.

Comment: Also change `$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST);` to `$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);` you're repeating `DB_HOST`

Comment: @Fred-ii- everything worked great, the only problem is the data.

Comment: Have you tried it without the port? `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');`

Comment: I feel Dagon's comment is something to concern yourself with.  There are far too many tutorials that show the basics and don't cover any aspect of security.  IMO, if you're going to learn how to do it, learn how to do it with security in mind so you don't find your self falling back to what you initially learned that had no security considerations.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I'll look for a tutorial that does implement security features and sticks to the basics. I apologize for the lack of concern. _But at the moment_, I'd really like to know why the data isn't being saved to the db as it should!

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes I have tried without the port. No errors popup, but no data is saved either.

Comment: Have a look at what I posted below. Your present code (fixed from some of my comments) did not work for me when testing. @WalkOfLife

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out: (your present code did not work for me) HTML form and PHP/SQL are all-in-one.

```
<?php
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');  
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'xxx');

$link = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
OR die("could not connect");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    // stored in a variable to shorten
    $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['input1']);

    // stored in a variable to TEST
    $sql = "INSERT INTO demo (input1) VALUES ('$value')"; 

    if(!mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    }

    else { echo "Success"; }

} // if(isset($_POST['submit']))

    mysqli_close($link);
?>

<form action="" method="post" />
<p>Input 1: <input type="text" name="input1" /></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I got a _Success_ message but nothing was added to the DB. I'm guessing that this has got to be a problem with phpmyadmin or the way I setup my tables.

Comment: Your screenshot shows `localhost` instead of `localhost:60` did you use `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost);` instead of `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:60');`? @WalkOfLife

Comment: And what about `localhost:3306` @WalkOfLife

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but phpmyadmin may not have been correctly setup. I have the following notifs: http://i.imgur.com/SoVBnFS.png

Comment: That could very well be the case @WalkOfLife

Comment: Still nothing with `localhost:3306`, I clicked on one of the notifs and it now says `PMA Database ... not OK [ Documentation ]
General relation features Disabled` When I click on the link to the documentation it redirects me to http://localhost:60/phpmyadmin/pmadb with an Error message: "The requested url... was not found on the server".

Comment: I've never used PHPmyadmin on `localhost` myself, always on a hosted server. Try and visit their website if there's a link in there. @WalkOfLife

Comment: I'll try and see if it works on my hosted server. If so, I'll just work with that from now on. I'll get back to you if it doesn't. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: You're quite welcome. I'm pretty sure it will work on a hosted server as it did on mine, which I tested my answer with. Keep me posted, cheers @WalkOfLife

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49907/discussion-between-walkoflife-and-fred-ii)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL used port 3306 as the default.  Does PHP connect directly to the database?  If yes, try making your port match.

Did you add permissions to MySQL to allow your app to connect and interact with the database?  You should read about GRANT and permissions.

But the comment by Dagon above is a serious one: exposting a database directly to the Internet should only be done if you're willing to have the data stolen, trashed, or both.

Comment: I'll read about that and get back to you. This is only for testing purposes and it's not directly exposed to the Internet. I appreciate your concern though.

Comment: Under 'Privileges" I have Grant Access to ALL.

Comment: So does everyone on the Internet, then.  Why not get it over with and put the root password in plain text so we can all see it when we "view  source"?