# Can't use demo: Unknown database 'demo'

Tags: php, mamp

I have this error when i try to submit to my demo database:
***Can't use demo: Unknown database 'demo'*** How do i get the server going?

Basic form:

```
<form action="demo.php" method="post" />
<p>Input 1: <input type="text" name="input1" /></p>
<p>Input 2: <input type="text" name="input2" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Server communication setup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>


<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'demo');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST['input1'];
$value2 = $_POST['input2'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (input1, input2) VALUES ('$value', '$value2')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

All my code should work and is from this tutorial: [Tutorial video link](https://youtu.be/BmHLvUdkCA0?list=PL530D33D6E548481F)
Here is download link to the original php files i have used:
[Original from tutorial: Basic php form](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4aeyq8n0fxv2b0d/demo.php?dl=0)
[Orignial from tutorial: Communication with server php-file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/srhkqa0jnwfwjrx/demo-form.php?dl=0)

[image: Screenshot of all]

Comment: can you create database with **demo** name

Comment: What you mean, it's called demo in the phpMyadmin?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465109/php-not-saving-data-to-database

Comment: **demo** is your table name .your database name is **forms1** @m_schou

Comment: Ok, how can i fix this error though? http://postimg.org/image/8z9095cot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your database name is **forms1** not **demo**. demo is your table name

Try this code

```
define('DB_NAME', 'forms1');//Your database name is forms1 not demo
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}
```

> Change this code because in your table column **input2 not available**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (input1) VALUES ('$value')";
```

Comment: Works now, but now error with: 'input2' in 'field list' http://postimg.org/image/psmvvfthx/

Comment: Is this enough for you to see table structure?http://postimg.org/image/4c24x1dq1/

Comment: You dont have a input2 column in the DB. You'll need to add a new column,

Comment: Ok, http://postimg.org/image/8z9095cot/ i get an error when i try to add an input 2 that is similar to input 1

Comment: close your browser and try again to create column @m_schou

Comment: closed browser and re-opened phpMyAdmin via MAMP and i got this error again: http://postimg.org/image/6j3cr9sit/

Comment: try this sql query    **ALTER TABLE `demo`
ADD COLUMN `input2` varchar(250)**

Comment: I'm not sure where to do that and how to make an sql query, how do i do that? 
If the make a new column by adding after input1 it works (http://postimg.org/image/j07jrwopn/) but if i used New from the side-bar(http://postimg.org/image/darb7lijf/) this makes an error for some reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92478/discussion-between-rahautos-and-m-schou).

Answer (score 2):

Your database is called "forms1" not "demo".. table is called "forms1".

Change `define('DB_NAME', 'demo');` to `define('DB_NAME', 'forms1');`

Comment: Works now, but now error with: 'input2' in 'field list' http://postimg.org/image/psmvvfthx/

Comment: What columns are in your "demo" database? Perhaps "input2" is not one of the columns?

Comment: Ok, http://postimg.org/image/8z9095cot/ i get an error when i try to add an input 2 that is similar to input 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your Database on mysql_connect

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

Comment: Ok like this?: 
$link = mysql_connect('demo', 'root', 'root');